# Problem with compilers when using cmake to build a Xcode project

Tags: c++, c, xcode, cmake

I have been using CMake for years to build my Xcode projects. Suddenly, maybe after upgrading the OSX (11.6) or maybe after upgrading the Xcode (13.0, commandline tools 13.0), cmake does not work anymore.

First let me give some of the things I have already tried so I am just not referred to an answered question and forgotten:

`sudo xcode-select --reset` This has no effect.

I have tried resetting the cmake variable manually with
`cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/cc"` and to other paths.  It still gives a "Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed." in the CMakeError.log.  No c compiler that I can find in my system seems to work including clang in various locations.

I have tried reseting the environmental variables CC, CXX, CLANG, etc to different paths.

This might have something to do with Anaconda which I have installed.

I created a test project to pinpoint the problem. In it is a main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and a CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

The in a build subdirectory I run

```
>>> cmake .. -G Xcode
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "../Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "../Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The beginning of CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log is:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: -march=core2;-mtune=haswell;-mssse3;-ftree-vectorize;-fPIC;-fPIE;-fstack-protector-strong;-O2;-pipe;-isystem;/opt/anaconda3/include
Id flags:  

The output was:
65
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

.
.
.
   clang-10: error: invalid Darwin version number: macos11.3
    clang-10: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-macos11.3'
 
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please show `echo $CC` and `echo $CXX`.

Comment: What's your CMake version? You might have to update it, to support the newer Xcode version.

Comment: Normally $ echo $CC
/usr/bin/Clang  but I have tried changing this to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

Comment: $ echo $CXX
/usr/bin/clang++

Comment: cmake version 3.18.2

Comment: Updated to cmake version 3.19.1.  No change.

Comment: If the Xcode generator is chosen, cmake wants to run xcodebuild, not clang. You still have something wrong with xcode, did something wrong with `xcode-select`. Follow the instructions here
https://gist.github.com/Justintime50/2349ff5e62555aa097acbf519bbc27af carefully.

Comment: I followed the instruction there and had no problems, but it did not change the problem.  I also re-installed Xcode for good measure.  No difference.

Comment: I still cannot figure this out. I've reinstall Xcode and command line tools.  No changes.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to workout with a similar problem setting some variables inside CMakeLists.txt. Is not a deffinitive solution, however. It needs a followup.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

==== EDIT =====

Following this idea I managed to fix this problem (which was one problem on my side too).

There's a problem with the variable CC and CXX created by Xcode. They try to do something like:

```
xcrun -find cc
```

The result of that, on my side is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
```

This is consistent and, if I look for that compiler, it exists. But, it doesn't work within CMake.

I manage to make it work setting those two variables to where they are pointing at:

```
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
export CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
```

After that, I managed to compile with CMake without setting the variable inside of the CMakeLists.txt file.

You should add those exports to the end of your .bash_profile